# Sql Server 2016 uses low RAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory

I have an SQL server 2016,

> version:
>   (SP2-CU4-OD) (KB4482972) - 13.0.5239.0 (X64)

The server is a Win 2016, with 64 GB RAM.
I have configured max memory for SQL to 54 GB, but it uses less than 1 GB.
Data are been migrated from an older SQL version.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please add "complete" output of `select @@version` in the question

Comment: @shanky wants the full output to see if you are running express because express has a limit of 1410MB(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-sp1-know-your-limits)

Comment: `uses less than 1 GB` according to _what_?

Comment: Hi, the SQL is a standard edition, in task manager I see that instance use less 1 GB, and I have about 58 GB free.

Comment: Don't use task  manager to monitor memory. Instead, use PMON or the DMV query `SELECT counter_name, cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name = N'Total Server Memory (KB)';`

Comment: How big is the database in the instance ? Is it heavely consumed or just "lying down" there ?

Answer (score 3):

Like @Shanky mentioned in the comment, it could be due to Express Edition accidently being installed instead of Standard or Enterprise. Due to the Database size size limit, I don't think you could even restore a large database, so you would notice almost immediately.

As an experiement, have you tried caching a lot of data in memory by doing several large SELECTs to see if it changes? SQL Server is fairly memory-hungry, but by default it doesn't use memory until it needs it, so if nothing has happened since the last restart, there's nothing in memory yet.